# Resgatar dados BD apenas preechidos

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Estou com um problema quando tenho de mostrar os dados da Base de dados e eles estão vazios Porque aparece o nome e fica o espaço em branco.

```
Nome: Pedro
Nome: Ricardo
Nome:
Nome:
Nome:
```

e queria saber se era possível alterar isso para so mostrar os dados Preenchidos

```
   <p><b>Nome :</b> '.$exibe["Nome1"].' &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; <b> Função :   </b>'.$exibe["Funcao1"].'</p>

        <p><b>Nome :</b> '.$exibe["Nome2"].' &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; <b> Função : </b> '.$exibe["Funcao2"].'</p>

        <p><b>Nome :</b> '.$exibe["Nome3"].' &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; <b> Função : </b> '.$exibe["Funcao3"].'</p>

        <p><b>Nome :</b> '.$exibe["Nome4"].' &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; <b> Função : </b> '.$exibe["Funcao4"].'</p>

        <p><b>Nome :</b> '.$exibe["Nome5"].' &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; <b> Função : </b> '.$exibe["Funcao5"].'</p>

        <p><b>Nome :</b> '.$exibe["Nome6"].' &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; <b> Função : </b> '.$exibe["Funcao6"].'</p>

        <p><b>Nome :</b> '.$exibe["Nome7"].' &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; <b> Função : </b> '.$exibe["Funcao7"].'</p>

        <p><b>Nome :</b> '.$exibe["Nome8"].' &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; <b> Função : </b> '.$exibe["Funcao8"].'</p>
```

Comment: Poderia colocar o cógido com problema? já tentou um `trim()` ?

Comment: alterei na pergunta. São varios nomes que podem não estar preenchidos

Comment: Creio que seja seu loop mal controlado. Posta o código aqui para podermos visualizar o problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso não funciona?

```
while($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($resultadoQuery) {
     if($exibe[nome] != NULL) {
          echo "<p><b>Nome: </b>$mostrar[nome] -- $mostrar[funcao]</p>
     }
```

EDIT:

Você não consegue fazer isso (igual postou no comentário):

```
<p>
      <?php if($exibe['nome6'] != NULL) {
            echo '<p><b>Nome: </b>'.$exibe['nome6'].'&nbsp;&nbsp; <b>Função: </b>'.$exibe['funcao6'];
           }
      ?>
</p>
```

<

Comment: Estou com um pequeno problema ao colocar esse IF dentro do php.<p>'
   if($exibe["Nome6"] != NULL) {
   echo '<p><b>Nome: </b>'.$exibe["Nome6"].' &nbsp;&nbsp; <b> Função : </b>'.$exibe["Funcao6"].
     }'</p>

Comment: Vou editar a resposta e mostrar pra você como faz.

Comment: Olhe a resposta editada e veja se foi isso, caso não tenha sido, especifique o erro que acontece.

Comment: Eu estava a ter um erro mas era porque me faltava um ; antes. e não utilizei o <?php

Answer (score 0):

Você pode modificar a query para

```
    SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE `nome` != NULL
```

Comment: Sim claro. Mas antes de aparecer o nome está texto a dizer "Nome:"

Comment: A dica do brhvitor6 pode resolver se seu banco estiver com este tipo de buraco (campos vazios). Caso não seja, o problema poderá estar em seu loop. Está aparecendo "Nome:" porque não é dado do banco mas sim html que você está inserindo na mão.

Comment: Mas não faço nenhum loop. mostro apenas os dados do BD por ordem

Comment: E como você está resgatando os N registros do banco? Só postando o código para termos uma idéia do que ocorre.